# Get Flag violation the policies from Google Drive when Uploading Android Studio project (.Rar) that have/using "github.Philjay:MPAndroidChart"

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a Android Studio project that using MPAndroidChart to create Chart. Whenever I try to upload the rar project to Google drive, I get flag that said the file is violated the policies from google, the file may be a harm. Mostly this will appear faster if I set sharing for the file. But I need to share this file, that why I use google drive. If I use another media to share, the people I need to share to, moslty will get flag too, 'Cause they have to send to another person using drive. Basiclly I have to use Google drive to send my project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biE8O.png)

At first, I didn't know where the problem was, so I seperate the project, create again new project. Add a part of old project, run part by part & add the okay one to new part and upload to drive to see what part is the problem, repeat again to bigger part to see what the reason get violation. So, everything is fine, I get to upload and share normal **UNTILL** I use github.Philjay:MPAndroidChart in the project to create the chart - it get flag.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkHse.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogv8r.png)

More details, I create many projects to test, there are some that important:

1. Projects before add anything relate to "github.Philjay:MPAndroidChart" - In layout and links in build.gradle and setting => Fine to upload & share.
2. Project that just add the links in build.gradle and setting, didn't use any chart in Activity => Okay to upload but get Falg
3. Project that have links in build.gradle and setting & chart in layout Activity => Okay to upload but get Falg
   => That's why I know the issue it's from "github.Philjay:MPAndroidChart".
   Some information relate to my project, I don't know if it help but I will mention here:

- The chart get data from sqlite build in the project.
- I create project step: New -> New project -> Empty View Activity.
- And I using "Java" to code.
- I'm using Windows 10.

Is there anything I can do to prevent/get rid of this flag?
Ask anything if you need more information. Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the exact error you get from Google Drive? Have you tried this with other libraries hosted on the same maven server?

Comment: Google drive marked my .rar as violent to policies of Google - this happend then I upload to google drive and share for mutiple people as long as they have the link to access. And I haven't try with orther libraries. But as I mention, same project but don't have any relate to MPAndroidChart is fine. Problem appear when I start add/use that library.

Comment: "Violent to policies of Google"? You haven't answered either of my questions. 1. Please include the **exact** message in your question, 2. try with a *different* library hosted in the same way. I doubt this has anything to do with MPAndroidChart itself.

Comment: Update here: Maybe the issue have something with my device, still not sure why it cause that error when I using the library. 
Anyway, the issue gone when I import .rar project by steps: File -> Export -> Export to Zip file in Android studio instead of right-click to the project file. Steps in android delete some temp file created when we run the project. And my issue is wipe away, upload good in google drive now. 
Thank you for spend time helping me. Have a nice day :)